# Change src of image on hover with array property

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm mapping through an array that contains properties such as `image: link to image` and `hover_image: link to image`

Is there a way to change an image on hover? Something sort of like this:

```
<img src={hover ? item.hover_image : item.image} />
```

If so, how can I define that the element is being hovered over, thank you!

Update: the `onMouseHover` or any other `onMouse` seems to not work on my image tag, here is the code:

```
{array.map((item, key) => {
  <div key={key}>
    <a target="_blank" href={item.link} >
      <img
        onMouseEnter={(e) => console.log(e.currentTarget.src)}
        alt={item.name}
        src={item.image}
  
      />
    </a>
  </div>
})}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change image when hover in Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63051245/change-image-when-hover-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React has two event handlers for that:

```
onMouseEnter
onMouseLeave
```

You could put those events on the component that you are hovering over and make them set a state variable, to track the hover state. e.g.:

```js
function YourOuterComponent({item}) {
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(null);
  return (
    <>
      <div id='whatever' 
           onMouseEnter={(e) => setHover(e.currentTarget.id)} 
           onMouseLeave={() => setHover(null)}>
        hover over me
      </div>
      <img src={hover ? item.hover_image : item.image} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Edit based on coments:

```
  {array.map((item, key) => (
    <div key={key}>
      <a target="_blank" href={item.link}>
        <img
          alt={item.name}
          src={item.image}
          onMouseEnter={(e) => {
            e.currentTarget.src = item.hover_image;
          }}
          onMouseLeave={(e) => {
            e.currentTarget.src = item.image;
          }}
        />
      </a>
    </div>
  ))}
```

Comment: This one seems to be close, but the image doesn't change, not sure what's missing

Comment: maybe the `id ` is `undefined`? Try to use `setHover(true)`. Also, is `item.hover_image` defined? Try to log `item`

Comment: `hover_image` exists, I tried `setHover(true)` method but it still doesn't wok

Comment: Hmm, I will have to see your code then

Comment: I've updated my question to clear up how my code looks like

Comment: see my updated answer, and try to implement all parts not only partially as you did in the question

Answer (score 0):

Inline JavaScript version**

```
<img src="a.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='b.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='a.jpg'" />
```

`this` refer to the current `img` tag

**Example :**

```html
<img width="100" height="100" src="https://onlinejpgtools.com/images/examples-onlinejpgtools/coffee-resized.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/08/25/20/42/field-6574455__340.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='https://onlinejpgtools.com/images/examples-onlinejpgtools/coffee-resized.jpg'" />
```

Comment: I'm using React so I tried `src={item.image} onMouseOver={e => (e.currentTarget.src = item.hoverimage)} onMouseOver={e => this.src === item.hoverimage} onMouseOut={e => this.src === item.image}` but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this behaviour by changing the `src` property of the target on which the event has occurred.

For an example:

```
function App() {
  const imgs = [
    {
      image:
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1644982654072-0b42e6636821?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80",
      hover_image:
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1648655514581-12808a5eb8c3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwzfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
    },
  ];

  const elements = imgs.map((img, i) => {
    return (
      <img
        key={i}
        onMouseOver={(e) => {
          e.target.src = img.hover_image;
        }}
        src={img.image}
        style={{ height: "200px", width: "200px" }}
      />
    );
  });

  return <div className="app">{elements}</div>;
}
```

Comment: It seems as the `onMouseOver` property doesn't work for me in general, I can't even console.log stuff with it on `img`. Same applies to `onMouseEnter`

Comment: Please console log the event object first to check if onMouseOver works or not.